# See source/medium of purchases in GA4 realtime-report

Tags: google-analytics

in the GA4 realtime-report you have a box with "Users by first users source / medium" and you have a box with "Conversion by event name". What I need would be a real-time box which shows the purches based on "users source / medium". Is this possible somehow?